# Using $this when not in object context on yii

Tags: php, yii

```
class ModelFile extends CoreModel{

public $var;
public $var2;

public static function getId() {
   $this->var = '123';
}
}
```

I have above model. I am facing issue while using assigned variable.
The error I get on above code is

```
Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context
```

Any idea of this issue?

Comment: Remove `static` from `getId` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access `$this` in static methods because they don't belong to any instance, but to the whole class instead. In your case, just remove `static` keyword.